# Ubuntu 12.10 - How to get sip phone Twinkle latest version working using deb or already existing package from any repository?

Tags: 12.10, package-management, phone, sip

In Fedora, ArchLinux Twinkle works without any problem just using there default package installer.

But since in Ubuntu 12.10 there is not anymore this package available using `apt-get install twinkle`

How to get this package installed using apt-get?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

building it from source makes sense, but twinkle tends to have a long list of dev dependencies so this may be more trouble than it sounds.  I found it simpler to just add the debian repos to the end of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
  deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
  deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

add these two, and then add two more sets, changing **stable** to **unstable** and **sid**, respectively.
The SID repo might not be completely necessary, but it has come in handy for me to have it there in other cases.

After an `apt-get update` you should now be able to do `apt-get install twinkle`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if Twinkle has been removed from the Ubuntu 12.10 repositories. I did a quick check at the official website, and it seems as if you can compile the program yourself. Have you taken a look at [their site](http://www.twinklephone.com/) under the **Downloads** section.

Comment: For reference [here's the removal bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=673900)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to just download a .deb package from here:
http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/twinkle

For example, here is the amd64 package currently available:

```
amd64   1:1.4.2-2+b2    1,717.4 kB  4,640.0 kB
```

This is the latest version at the time of writing.

I think downloading the deb package would be preferrable to adding the Debian repos as suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/a/280414